# complex integral over a closed path.

Tags: soft-question, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I need to solve the following complex integral

$$
\oint_{\gamma}z^4\sin(z)dz
$$
where $\gamma:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-2|=2\}$.

But I see that $f(z)=z^4\sin(z)$ is holomorphic in $\gamma$ so, by Cauchy's integral theorem this integral must be zero.

I feel that I have a mistake, If I have it, can someone tell me which is it?

Comment: No mistake. You are right.

Comment: You indicated that your function is holomorphic. Now does the given function have an anti derivative ? If so what does that mean for the outcome of your integral?

Comment: I agree with baharampuri.

Comment: @imranfat If the function has a antiderivative, the outcome of the integral is the difference between the antiderivative evaluated  in initial and end point of $\gamma$. So, again the integral must be zero.

Comment: @baharampuri Do you think Principal value has to be considered since there is a pole on the contour?

Comment: No pole. Only zeros.

Comment: @baharampuri How stupid I was...what was happening to me...